# Debian Sid, AMD RS880 [Radeon HD 4250], black screen on boot

Tags: xorg, hardware, graphics, radeon, amd

My computer booted under Debian Wheezy (3.2 kernel) with no graphics problems whatsoever.  After updating to sid (3.10 kernel), the screen goes black (that is, the display flashes a bit and then goes into power-saving mode) and turns off whenever the kernel tries to set up the radeon framebuffer (both if I boot without the `nomodeset` option and if I load the module via `modprobe radeon modeset=1`).  I then compiled the kernel (both 3.10 and 3.11), Mesa and the xorg driver for myself with the same results.

`lspci -s 01:05.0 -vv`:

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4250] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 9715
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 1: I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at febf0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Region 5: Memory at fea00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

`dmesg | grep -i 'drm|radeon'`:

```
[    6.995487] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    7.744080] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[    7.744125] [drm:radeon_init] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
[  395.010450] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[  395.010779] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RS880 0x1002:0x9715 0x1849:0x9715).
[  395.010828] [drm] register mmio base: 0xFEBF0000
[  395.010859] [drm] register mmio size: 65536
[  395.015827] radeon 0000:01:05.0: VRAM: 512M 0x00000000C0000000 - 0x00000000DFFFFFFF (512M used)
[  395.015863] radeon 0000:01:05.0: GTT: 512M 0x00000000A0000000 - 0x00000000BFFFFFFF
[  395.015898] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=512M, BAR=256M
[  395.015930] [drm] RAM width 32bits DDR
[  395.016192] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[  395.016223] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
[  395.016261] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 131072, num gpu pages 131072
[  395.030829] [drm] Loading RS780 Microcode
[  395.085860] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x00000000C0040000).
[  395.085978] radeon 0000:01:05.0: WB enabled
[  395.086019] radeon 0000:01:05.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x00000000a0000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8801f7aacc00
[  395.086065] radeon 0000:01:05.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x00000000a0000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8801f7aacc0c
[  395.086109] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 1 (10.10.2010).
[  395.086147] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[  395.086201] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[  395.086502] radeon 0000:01:05.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  395.118357] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[  395.118455] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 1 usecs
[  395.118664] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[  395.118716] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[  395.119245] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[  395.119283] [drm] Connector 0:
[  395.119319] [drm]   VGA-1
[  395.119357] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e40 0x7e40 0x7e44 0x7e44 0x7e48 0x7e48 0x7e4c 0x7e4c
[  395.119397] [drm]   Encoders:
[  395.119433] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[  395.119470] [drm] Connector 1:
[  395.119505] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[  395.119540] [drm]   HPD3
[  395.119577] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e50 0x7e50 0x7e54 0x7e54 0x7e58 0x7e58 0x7e5c 0x7e5c
[  395.119617] [drm]   Encoders:
[  395.119652] [drm]     DFP3: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_LVTMA
[  395.119715] [drm] radeon: power management initialized
[  395.183376] [drm] fb mappable at 0xD0142000
[  395.183417] [drm] vram apper at 0xD0000000
[  395.184903] [drm] size 9216000
[  395.184939] [drm] fb depth is 24
[  395.184975] [drm]    pitch is 7680
[  395.185145] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[  395.380720] radeon 0000:01:05.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[  395.380813] radeon 0000:01:05.0: registered panic notifier
[  395.381119] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.34.0 20080528 for 0000:01:05.0 on minor 0
```

My Xorg.log is here: http://lpaste.net/92865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a kernel bug.  For this version of the kernel, a line in the radeon KMS drivers needs to be tweaked and the kernel rebuilt.  Most of this is moot, though, because it is fixed in newer kernel versions.